# Eigen: How do you store a matrix of unknown size as a member in a class?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I have been teaching myself C++ recently and wanted to try it out on a new project. I decided to build a very simple machine learning library using Eigen to store and manipulate data. I wanted to have a data class that stores a feature matrix and that can perform shuffle and partition operations on said matrix.

My trouble lies in determining the type of the member matrix. Ideally, I could call the constructor with an Eigen matrix that has already been created, and have the member matrix take that type.

What type should I make the member matrix if I want its type to be initialized 
based on the type of matrix passed into the constructor? Is there a way to do this without specifying any type of template arguments?

```
  template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
class Data{
    private:
        Eigen::MatrixBase<T1,T2,T3> X; 
    public:
        Data(Eigen::Matrix<T1,T2,T3> feature_matrix ): X{feature_matrix};
};


 int main()
  {
    Eigen::Matrix<int,2,2> m;
    m<<1,2,3,4 ;

    Data d(m);  //doesn't work because Data is missing template args

   return 0;
  }
```

To add to this question, since there doesn't seem to be a move constructor for the matrix class, are there any smart ways to construct a Data class without copying a matrix into the class?

Comment: Consider looking at [_The special value Dynamic_](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html)

Answer (score 3):

> What type should I make the member matrix if I want its type to be initialized based on the type of matrix passed into the constructor? Is there a way to do this without specifying any type of template arguments?

Directly... I don't know how.

But if you accept to use a template "make" function

```
template <typename T, int I1, int I2>
Data<T, I1, I2> makeData (Eigen::Matrix<T, I1, I2> em)
 { return em; }
```

using `auto` (if you can use C++11 or C++14) you can initialize `d` as follows

```
auto d = makeData(m);
```

P.s.: I suppose that your `Data` receive, as template parameter, a type and two ints; not three types.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to a single template argument given that there are typedefs for the `Eigen::Matrix` template parameters. For example, suppose that `Eigen::Matrix` has the following declarations:

```
namespace Eigen
{
    template<class cell_type, int rows, int columns>
    class Matrix
    {
    public:
        typedef cell_type CellType;
        static const int Rows = rows;
        static const int Columns = columns;

        //Other stuff
    }
}
```

Then you can write your `Data` class like so:

```
template<class matrix_type>
class Data
{
private:
    Eigen::MatrixBase<typename matrix_type::CellType, matrix_type::Rows, matrix_type::columns> X;

    //Rest
}
```

And instantiate like so:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int,2,2> mat_type;
mat_type m;
m<<1,2,3,4 ;

Data<mat_type> d(m);
```

You cannot forego passing a template argument to `Data` class because it has a member that needs to hold differing types of matrices (I assume).